# Can't find method GetCellValue in C# when trying to read values in Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I'm going according to the MS [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx#sectionSection1) for retrieving Excel values from a spreadsheet using OpenXML

Using directives as specified

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
```

But for the life of me I cannot get VS2013 to recognise the method. In bold below.

```
string value = GetCellValue(fileName, "Sheet1", "A1");
```

What am I missing? I'm using **.Net 4.6.1** and Office 365.
I've googled it but can't find any specific reference to the methods API

FYI I'm trying to create a dynamic read for simple data from a spreadsheet to pack into a class object and fire off to a clients web service

Comment: Read deeper in the tutorial. There is a definition for GetCellValue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx#sectionSection6

Comment: @Pierre-AlainVigeant That still doesn't show the class it's defined in. The example on their documentation is quite simply broken. It would be impossible for `GetCellValue` to ever work without the new `C#6` using statements (which they do not mention), or unless the code is inside the same class as that method.

Comment: The article date back from 2013, it has nothing to do with C#6. They expect you to place all the code in a single class along with the two using. The article don't define any classes.

Comment: To state it clear: There is no such method "in C#". Not in `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging` and not in `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet`.It is a sample method shown in the tutorial. If it does what you want, just copy it and put it in your code.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainVigeant I didn't mean it was related to `C#6`, only that their example *might* have been possible if they were talking about `C#6` but forgot to show the using statement. However, I see what you mean now; though I still think it's a bit strange to have an article on a particular method which isn't included in the standard library, and you need copy & paste it from their documentation. Nevertheless, your solution is correct :)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @Pierre-AlainVigeant, I ended up writing my own method using interop, a hack but it did the job

Answer (score 3):

If you scroll down the tutorial to the Sample Code section you will see the method the tutorial describes. Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.Write(GetCellValue("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\test.xlsx", "Sheet1", "A1"));
    }

    // Retrieve the value of a cell, given a file name, sheet name, 
    // and address name.
    public static string GetCellValue(string fileName,
        string sheetName,
        string addressName)
    {
        string value = null;

        // Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document =
            SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            // Retrieve a reference to the workbook part.
            WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            // Find the sheet with the supplied name, and then use that 
            // Sheet object to retrieve a reference to the first worksheet.
            Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().
              Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

            // Throw an exception if there is no sheet.
            if (theSheet == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("sheetName");
            }

            // Retrieve a reference to the worksheet part.
            WorksheetPart wsPart =
                (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));

            // Use its Worksheet property to get a reference to the cell 
            // whose address matches the address you supplied.
            Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
              Where(c => c.CellReference == addressName).FirstOrDefault();

            // If the cell does not exist, return an empty string.
            if (theCell != null)
            {
                value = theCell.InnerText;

                // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
                // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
                // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
                // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
                // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
                // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
                // the words TRUE or FALSE.
                if (theCell.DataType != null)
                {
                    switch (theCell.DataType.Value)
                    {
                        case CellValues.SharedString:

                            // For shared strings, look up the value in the
                            // shared strings table.
                            var stringTable =
                                wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            // If the shared string table is missing, something 
                            // is wrong. Return the index that is in
                            // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
                            // the table.
                            if (stringTable != null)
                            {
                                value =
                                    stringTable.SharedStringTable
                                    .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                            }
                            break;

                        case CellValues.Boolean:
                            switch (value)
                            {
                                case "0":
                                    value = "FALSE";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    value = "TRUE";
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            document.Close();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```